# How to organize parameter values in an array of arrays to input into a function?

Tags: matlab, parameters, combinations, permutation

Hopefully I can clearly express my problem: I have a probability density function which is a convolution of two distributions. My function requires that I feed it a mean and variance pair for each distribution. I am trying to organize all the different combinations of mean and variance pairs I want to evaluate.

The first thing I do is just form the pairs with this code:

```
mm=linspace(.1, 1, 2); % mean values
vv=linspace(.1, 2, 2); % variance values
N=length(mm);
n=length(vv);

for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:n
        p{(i-1)*N+j} = [mm(i), vv(j)];
    end
end
```

So my pairs are, `p{1} = [.1, .1], p{2} = [.1, 2], p{3} = [1., .1], p{4} = [1.,2.]`. Now, I'm stuck on forming all possible combinations of these pairs with the requirement that I don't have any 'repeats' - what I mean by repeat is that my PDF doesn't care if I feed it `[p{1}, p{2}]` or `[p{2}, p{1}]` - it will evaluate the same (basically, my PDF is the distribution of exit times and I only care about the total time, which is why order doesn't matter).

So basically, I want an array that looks like this:

```
P(1) = [p{1}, p{1}], P(2) = [p{1}, p{2}],
P(3) = [p{1}, p{3}], P(4) = [p{1}, p{4}],
P(5) = [p{2}, p{2}], P(6) = [p{2}, p{3}],
P(7) = [p{2}, p{4}], P(8) = [p{3}, p{3}],
P(9) = [p{3}, p{4}], P(10) = [p{4}, p{4}]
```

I am trying to do this, but having a hard time on indexing

```
for i = 1:N*n
    for j = i:N*n
        P = [p{i},p{j}];
    end
end
```

So once I fix that, I can feed my PDF all ten of these combinations to evaluate. Which brings me to another issue - my PDF is written in such a way that it takes 4 arguments `function Y=myPDF(m1,v1,m2,v2)`. For example, how would I break `[p{1},p{2}]` apart so that the mean and variance from `p{1}` would be assigned to `m1,v1` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach on your indices using [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
mm=linspace(.1, 1, 2)'; % mean values
vv=linspace(.1, 2, 2)'; % variance values
N=length(mm);
n=length(vv);

p = cell(N, n);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:n
        p{(i-1)*N+j} = [mm(i), vv(j)];
    end
end

temp = nchoosek([1:N*n, 1:N*n], 2); % Get all the permutations
temp = sort(temp, 2); % Sort each permutation by row for an easier unique call
idx = unique(temp, 'rows'); % Get all unique permutations
```

You can then use these indices to reference your data:

```
P = cell(length(idx), 1);
for ii = 1:length(idx)
    P{ii} = {p(idx(ii, 1)), p(idx(ii, 2))};
end
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but it is a starting point.

Edit: And for the second part of your question, you can dump everything into a double array with this *beautiful* line of code:

```
test = [reshape([p{idx(:,1)}], 2, [])', reshape([p{idx(:,2)}], 2, [])'];
```

Which returns:

```
test =

    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000
    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000    2.0000
    0.1000    0.1000    1.0000    0.1000
    0.1000    0.1000    1.0000    2.0000
    0.1000    2.0000    0.1000    2.0000
    0.1000    2.0000    1.0000    0.1000
    0.1000    2.0000    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0000    0.1000    1.0000    0.1000
    1.0000    0.1000    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0000    2.0000    1.0000    2.0000
```

Comment: Why did you change from 2 to 4 when you declared `mm` and `vv`. I only have two values for each.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I wasn't too clear in my question - I would prefer P to not be a cell. Instead of doing the reshape that you do to help address the second part of my question, do you see a problem with just doing this:

`P = zeros(length(idx,4);
for ii = 1:length(idx)
P(ii,:) = [p{idx(ii,1)},p{idx(ii,2)}]
end`

`P` is then the same as your `test` above.

Comment: Sure. You don't need the intermediate `P` step if `test` is what you're looking for; it's dependent only on `p` and the unique permutations in `idx` (no loop needed). I included it because it was one of the steps of your question.